# Filling empty mesh

Tags: mesh

I want to fill my mesh.
It is empty but I want it like the other mesh.

Pic: [image]

Comment: Look at the screw modifier and/or the spin edit tool.

Comment: Can you send the blend file please?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a `screw` modifier on the end part. However you need to have a symetric shape in order for the modifier to work correctly.

Starting point, you have the shape at the end:
[image]
Delete the bottom portion of your mesh:
[image]
Select the `screw` modifier in the modifier tab, choose the right axis and deselect smooth shading:
[image]

There you have it: the vertice line has been rotated 360° to fill a shape:
[image]

Alternatively you can use the spin tool, which is very easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

If your mesh is a curve, you must convert it to a mesh using the keyboard shortcut: alt+c go to edit mode on the mesh, make sure everything is selected and then push the F key on the keyboard. This should fill in the mesh. (The way